# ExtJs: update() & autoScroll not working

Tags: extjs4, scrollbar

I'm trying to update the `html` of a `tabPanel`. The scrollbar is there on the initial load, but then on `update` the scroll bar disappears.

This is my code:

```
    var text = "a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>";

    years = [];
    items = [];
    for(i=this_year; i>2002; i--) {
        years.push(i);
    }

    for(i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {

        items.push({
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            title: years[i],
            id: 'tabs' + years[i],
            activeTab: 0,
            autoScroll: true,
            html: text, // this works just fine
        });
    }

    var tp = new Ext.TabPanel({
        renderTo: div,
        id: 'tabs',
        activeTab: 0,
        items: items,
        autoFit: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        listeners: {
            'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab){
                // dynamically update the html
            }
        }
    });

    // but if i instead use this the scrollbar disappears
    Ext.get('tabs' + 2014).update(text);
```

Is there some other way to update the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with `contentEl` and jQuery's `appendTo`:

```
years = [];
items = [];
for(i=this_year; i>2002; i--) {
    years.push(i);
}

for(i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {

    $('<div id="tabs' + years[i] + '"></div>').appendTo("#some_div");

    items.push({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        title: years[i],
        id: 'foo-tabs' + years[i],
        activeTab: 0,
        autoScroll: true,
        contentEl: 'tabs' + years[i],
    });
}

var tp = new Ext.TabPanel({
    renderTo: div,
    id: 'foo-tabs',
    activeTab: 0,
    items: items,
    autoFit: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    listeners: {
        'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab){

        }
    }
});

$('some html').appendTo('#tabs' + year);
```